# Django + React app deployed on GAE Flex but static files won't work

Tags: reactjs, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, infrastructure

I have a Django/React application. The frontend is being served by Django using static files. Because I am using GeoDjango, I've had to move from using GAE standard to GAE flex (to build a container with GDAL as it is required for GeoDjango etc).

However, now my site won't load and requests get cancelled when trying to load the static content.

I have an `app.yaml` which looks like this:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT appname.wsgi

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
env_variables:
  DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "someVariable"
  GOOGLE_API_KEY: "someVariable"
handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/
  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

My app settings contain the cloud storage url like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REACT_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(REACT_APP_DIR, 'build', 'static'),
]
```

And last but not least, this is the view that renders the frontend via Django:

```
class FrontendAppView(View):
    """
    Serves the compiled frontend entry point (only works if you have run `yarn
    run build`).
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        print(os.path.join(settings.REACT_APP_DIR, 'build', 'index.html'))
        try:
            with open(
                    os.path.join(settings.REACT_APP_DIR, 'build',
                                 'index.html')) as f:
                return HttpResponse(f.read())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            logging.exception('Production build of app not found')
            return HttpResponse(
                """
                    This URL is only used when you have built the production
                    version of the app. Visit http://localhost:3000/ instead, or
                    run `yarn run build` to test the production version.
                    """,
                status=501,
            )
```

My site is making calls like this:
`http://www.domain.co.uk/static/css/main.d73ff749.chunk.css` but the status for the various requests changes to `cancelled` after a few seconds.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making use of [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/).

Now the website is getting the static content and rendering as expected.